# How to send Notifications to Android App with Firebase Cloud Messaging with AppEngine Python

Tags: android, python, google-app-engine, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

this is my first time posting a question to stackoverflow, so I will do my best to expand on my question in a clear manner.  I've beat my head against the wall in trying to find an answer, but am currently stuck, so any insight offered would be greatly appreciated.

I am trying to send FCM messages to an Android app that I've developed.  I followed the Android Quickstart tutorial: https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/client

I am able to send Notification messages to my app from the Firebase Cloud Messenging composer, and the notifications are properly accepted by the app and when the app is visible, loads the data payload in a simple Activity -> TextView.

Now, I am trying to push the notifications from a Google App Engine server app using the Python SDK, built upon the Webapp2 framework, and I am unclear how to go about doing this.

In a RequestHandler, I want to push data received from a POST request to the Notification.  I have written some basic code in an attempt to do this:

```
class SendDetails(webapp2.RequestHandler):
def post(self):
    url = 'https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send'
    body = {
        "data": {
            "title": "mytitle",
            "body": "mybody",
            "url": "myurl"
        },
        "notification": {
            "title": "My web app name",
            "body": "message",
            "content_available": "true"
        },
        "to": "AIzaSyAqv4hjGC1Z5.......XyQ",
    }

    headers = {"Content-Type": "application/json",
               "Authorization": "AIzaSyDhIji4X6h0VQwor.......lrr2zo"}

    try:
        form_data = urllib.urlencode(body)

        headers = {"Content-Type": "application/json",
                   "Authorization": "key=AIzaSyDhI.......mOUXlrr2zo"}
        result = urlfetch.fetch(
            url='https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send',
            payload=form_data,
            method=urlfetch.POST,
            headers=headers)
        self.response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'text/plain'
        self.response.write(result)
    except urlfetch.Error:
        logging.exception('Caught exception fetching url')
```

When I run the code on dev_appserver, and trigger the RequestHandler via a browser, I get a "POST HTTP/1.1 200 68" response.  I am unsure how to interpret the "68" code.

Depending on how I format the request, sometimes I am redirected to the 
"Firebase Cloud Messaging HTTP Protocol" webpage at https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/http-server-ref which tells me that I am on the right track.

Next, in order to gain some insight, I have tried sending Notifications from a Chrome app called Advanced REST Client (ARC) which allows me to build HTTP requests and forward to the FCM server.

Here is an example of what I send to the FCM server:

Content-Type: application/json
Authorization: key=AIzaSyDhIji4X6h0........2zo

{"to": "AIzaSyAqv4hjGC1Z5........cfSRU_gXyQ",
  "data": {
    "message": "This is a Firebase Cloud Messaging Topic Message!",
   }}

I get the following response:

```
{
"multicast_id": 
7345322951926226000
,
"success": 0,
"failure": 1,
"canonical_ids": 0,
"results": [
  {
"error": "InvalidRegistration"
}
],
}
```

I am sure that I am missing something simple, but as a newcomer to AppEngine and Firebase, I am not sure where I am going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Well, after much further investigation, the answer was (as usual) right under my nose, but not quite so obvious.

For my testing, I was using the legacy server key assigned by Firebase/Google and not the newer one that they recommend -- even though it clearly states in the Firebase Console / Messenger section that it is still useable.  As soon as I plugged in the new key, everything worked as intended.